# How to extract the web service method name in mule <cxf:proxy-service>

Tags: cxf, mule, interceptor

I am working with mule `<cxf:proxy-service>` and need to extract the web service method name to attach to message for later use.

We've a service proxy class implementing Callable interface. Initially we tried to get operation name like this:

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {  
    try {
        MuleMessage inboundMessage = eventContext.getMessage();

        Set<String> props = inboundMessage.getInvocationPropertyNames();
        System.out.println("CXF invocation properties ==> " + props);
        System.out.println("CXF invocation property ==> " +  inboundMessage.getInvocationProperty("cxf_operation"));
```

but the above code gives incorrect operation name. (We've 4 operations in service and it always give the 2nd operation name). Below is the mule flow used for this:

```
<flow name="proxyService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="${some.address}"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">

        <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:abc.wsdl"
            namespace="http://namespace"
            service="MyService">

        </cxf:proxy-service>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="com.services.MyServiceProxy" />
```

So, I resorted to write an inbound cxf interceptor to extract the operation name. I wrote below interceptor which works fine with `<cxf:jaxws-service>` but not with `<cxf:proxy-service>` element.

Here is my interceptor:

```
public class GetCXFOperation extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

public GetCXFOperation() {
    super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);

}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    Exchange exchange = message.getExchange();
    Endpoint ep = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);
    OperationInfo op = exchange.get(OperationInfo.class);
    if(op != null){
    System.out.println("Operation Name: " + op.getName().getLocalPart());
    } else{
         Object nameProperty = exchange.get("org.apache.cxf.resource.operation.name"); 
    if(nameProperty != null)

    System.out.println(nameProperty.toString());
    }

}
```

}

Seeking guidance as to how to extract operation name in `<cxf:proxy-service>`? Is there an easy mule way of getting correct answer? Or is there a different phase in which I should be invoking my interceptor? What phases work with `<cxf:proxy-service>`

Comment: Can't you get it from the SOAPAction header?

Comment: soapAction attribute in wsdl is not populated

Comment: I mean in the incoming call.

Comment: Can you please explain how to get the header information you mentioned and in what phase

Comment: In `OnCall` get the inbound message property named `SOAPAction`.

Comment: This is coming as Null. Here is the snippet I used:  System.out.println("SOAPAction invocation property ==> " + inboundMessage.getInvocationProperty("SOAPAction"));

Comment: okay I see this. `SOAPAction` is an inboundProperty and not an invocationProperty on inboundMessage but it is populated only when soapAction attribute in `<soap:operation>` tag in wsdl is populated otherwise not. On working with `<cxf:jaxws-service>` element, I've ways to get OperationInfo but it is not available with `<cxf:proxy-service>` element, may be of its proxy nature, not sure though. It looks like there is no other option than to populate soapAction attribute in wsdl unless you tell me one.

Comment: David, is `<cxf:proxy-service>` element well described in your Mule in Action **2nd edition**. Please let me know your thoughts